# How to prove that a triangle can be rotated around a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

Question -

> Triangle ABC contains a convex polygon P. Prove that there exists a triangle
>   congruent to ABC that also contains P and has a side parallel to a side of P.